# Creating a Tileset Source with Mapbox API

Tags: node.js, axios, mapbox

I am currently trying to create a Mapbox Tileset Source with this API:
https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/mapbox-tiling-service/#create-a-tileset-source

If I use curl, it works fine, but when I try to POST to it from my Node.js Backend, it returns an error.

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const fsPromises = fs.promises;
const FormData = require("form-data");
const form = new FormData();

geoJson = JSON.stringify(geoJsonObject);
let buf = Buffer.from(geoJson);
await fsPromises.writeFile(gpxFile, buf);
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(gpxFile));
axios
  .post(
    "https://api.mapbox.com/tilesets/v1/sources/..removed-user-account.../hello-world?access_token=" + mapboxToken,
    form,
    form.getHeaders()
  )
  .then(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

And here is a part of the error:

```
data: {
  message: 'No file data in request. Expected 1 file named "file".'
},
status: 400,
statusText: 'Bad Request',
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
config: {
  transitional: [Object],
  adapter: [Function: xhrAdapter],
  transformRequest: [Array],
  transformResponse: [Array],
  timeout: 0,
  xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
  maxContentLength: -1,
  maxBodyLength: -1,
  validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
  headers: [Object],
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------216718757074155301801217',
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/tilesets/v1/sources/...removed...',
  data: [FormData]
},
request: XMLHttpRequest {
  upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
  [Symbol(flag)]: [Object],
  [Symbol(properties)]: [Object]
}
```

So I am not sure what goes wrong here, I am passing a file, so why does the server reply with 'No file data in request. Expected 1 file named "file".' ?
Anyone has had success with this API endpoint yet?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it like this:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import fetch, { fileFromSync, FormData } from 'node-fetch';

const USERNAME = <USERNAME_HERE>;

const MAPBOX_BASE_URL = 'https://api.mapbox.com';
// Create a secret token on https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens/create
// NOTE: You need the following permission:
// - tilesets:list
// - tilesets:read
// - tilesets:write
const MAPBOX_TOKEN = <TOKEN_HERE>

const TILESET_ID_MAX_LENGTH = 32;

interface TilesetSource {
  file_size: number;
  files: number;
  id: string;
  source_size: number;
}

const upload = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const tilesetSourceId = nanoid(TILESET_ID_MAX_LENGTH);
  const tilesetSourceUrl = new URL(
    `tilesets/v1/sources/${USERNAME}/${tilesetSourceId}`,
    MAPBOX_BASE_URL,
  );
  tilesetSourceUrl.searchParams.append('access_token', MAPBOX_TOKEN);

  const body = new FormData();
  body.append(
    'file',
    fileFromSync('./path/to/data.geojson.ld'),
  );

  await fetch(tilesetSourceUrl.href, {
    method: 'post',
    body,
  });
}
```